# Bound mismatch when drawing buffer to screen (golang.org/x/exp/shiny/screen)

Tags: go

I am trying to use golang.org/x/exp/shiny/screen to create a windows and then paint a buffer on the screen.

I have assigned same bounds (height and width) to the window and the buffer I am publishing on the window, but there seems to be a mismatch when I see the results.

You can see in the picture, that the blue buffer which is uploaded to the window is not covering it completely.

[image]

```golang
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/exp/shiny/driver"
    "golang.org/x/exp/shiny/screen"
    "golang.org/x/mobile/event/key"
    "golang.org/x/mobile/event/lifecycle"
)

const (
    Row = 32
    Col = 64
)

// Colors
var (
    Black = color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 1.0}
    White = color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 1.0}
    Blue  = color.RGBA{0, 0, 255, 1.0}
)

func main() {

    go driver.Main(func(s screen.Screen) {
        opts := screen.NewWindowOptions{
            Height: Row,
            Width:  Col,
            Title:  "Chip-8 VM",
        }

        window, err := s.NewWindow(&opts)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Unable to create display window: ")
            log.Fatal(err)
            return
        }

        defer window.Release()

        dim := image.Point{Col, Row}
        drawBuff, err := s.NewBuffer(dim)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        defaultDrawToBuffer(drawBuff.RGBA())

        log.Print("Window bounds: ", opts)
        log.Printf("Buffer bounds: %s", drawBuff.Bounds())
        log.Printf("Buffer size: %s", drawBuff.Size())

        window.Upload(image.Point{}, drawBuff, drawBuff.Bounds())
        window.Publish()

        for {
            e := window.NextEvent()
            switch e := e.(type) {

            case lifecycle.Event:
                if e.To == lifecycle.StageDead {
                    return
                } else if e.To == lifecycle.StageFocused {
                    log.Print("Focus back on the screen!")
                }

            case key.Event:
                log.Print("pressed key: ", e.Code)
                // exit game
                if e.Code == key.CodeEscape {
                    return
                }
            case error:
                log.Print(e)
            }

        }
    })

    for {
    }

}

// Bounds: (0,0)-(64,32)
func defaultDrawToBuffer(img *image.RGBA) {
    b := img.Bounds()

    log.Printf("Bounds: %s", b.String())

    for x := b.Min.X; x < b.Max.X; x++ {
        for y := b.Min.Y; y < b.Max.Y; y++ {
            img.SetRGBA(x, y, Blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify an initial size of `width=62, height=32`, these are sizes in pixels. Which means you want your window to be "tiny". Windows usually have a *minimum* size (often dictated by window controls), and seemingly this minimum size is bigger than your intended size. So the blue rectangle you draw will not will the whole window (which will not be less than the minimum size).

If you increase the size, e.g. `Rows = 300, Cols = 600`, then it will fill your window.

Also, drop the `go` keyword when calling `driver.Main()`, some OS-specific libraries require it to be called from the `main` goroutine. And so remove the empty `for` from `main()`, `driver.Main()` blocks until your app should exit.

Also, this still won't guarantee you see the blue rectangle, as if the window (screen) is refreshed / cleared, a redraw might be necessary.

So instead move your drawing logic to the event loop, and execute it for the `paint.Event` events:

```
case paint.Event:
    defaultDrawToBuffer(drawBuff.RGBA())
    window.Upload(image.Point{}, drawBuff, drawBuff.Bounds())
    window.Publish()
```

Comment: hey, thanks so much. 
1st: if there's other code logic with having this window, should that code logic be called in separate goroutine and have the window logic in the main one?

2nd: how will the paint.Event event be invoked? what action/buffer should I modify so that this logic is eventually invoked to upload and publish to the screen?
Thanks

Comment: @killerx Yes, you may launch other goroutines, but `driver.Main()` should be called from the `main`. You have an event loop, and when a repaint is required, your event loop will receive a `paint.Event` event, so that case will be executed.